# Hover out from two divs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a look at the following JQuery code:

```
function my_hover()
{ 
$( "#up,#down" ).hover(
   function() {
       $("#up").animate({
    "background-color": "#020306"
         });               
    $("#down").animate({
        "background-color": "#171716"
    });           
      },
function() {
       $("#up").css("background-color","#C8CACF" );       
   $("#down").css("background-color","#FAFAF8" );
      }
   );
}
```

There are two divs: #up,#down which I cannot wrap into a parent div(due to design restrictions). What I want to do is to animate the change in background color whenever #up or #down are being hovered. However, in case the mouse leaves one div by going directly to the other(the two divs are stuck together vertically) I do not want the last two lines of the above code being applied. I want them to be applied only when mouse hovers out from **both** divs. How may I achieve that?  At users.sch.gr/ellhn you may see what is happening with the above code in the first left rectangle with the target photo (transition between up and down provokes change of color and that's not desirable).
Thank you

Comment: always provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo. It's help to understand the propblem

Comment: One method would be to use `setTimeout()` to slightly delay the hover out functionality, then in the hover in handler call `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: I visited your website, but still could not understand what exactly is your question, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Possible fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TudqT/

Comment: Dear Jared, your fiddle does exactly the same with what I described. However, my two divs are stuck vertically and I want to prevent changes in background color when pass from one to other...

Comment: I know it's the same, it's meant to be a demo that others can fiddle with. This is what @RakeshKumar was asking for. `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="up">Up</div>
<div id="down">down</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{ transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;}
#up{background:#C8CACF;}
#down{background:#FAFAF8;}
#up.up-hover{background-color:green;}
#down.down-hover{background-color:yellow;}
```

**Script**

```
$('#up, #down').mouseenter(function(){
    //alert('hi')
    $("#up").addClass('up-hover');               
    $("#down").addClass('down-hover');  
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    //alert('hi')
    $("#up").removeClass('up-hover');               
    $("#down").removeClass('down-hover');  
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TudqT/2/)

Comment: This doesn't take into account hovering off one and onto another and blocking the animation if the two are next next to each other. See: http://jsfiddle.net/TudqT/4/

Comment: for this both element should have parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Using the technique @nnnnn alluded to, e.g., using a timeout:

```
(function init() {
    var $up = $('#up'),
        $down = $('#down'),
        hovered = false;

    $up.hover(over, out);
    $down.hover(over, out);

    function over() {
        hovered = true;

        $up.css({
            "background-color": "#020306"
        });
        $down.css({
            "background-color": "#171716"
        });
    }

    function out() {
        setTimeout(function to() {
            if (!hovered) {
                $up.css("background-color", "#C8CACF");
                $down.css("background-color", "#FAFAF8");
            }

        }, 1000);

        hovered = false;
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TudqT/3/

And with the elements inline next to each other, instead of vertically aligned:

http://jsfiddle.net/TudqT/5/